# Checking the sum of a series (another)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need your help please, I don’t know why we have:
 $$\sum _ { | \alpha | \leq k } \xi ^ { 2 \alpha } = \left( 1 + | \xi | ^ { 2 } \right) ^ { k}  ,
$$  with $k \in \mathbf { N }$ and  $ \xi \in  \mathbf { R } ^ { N } $

if we take $k=1$, it looks like a wrong equality

Maybe because we’re in $ \mathbf { R } ^ { N }$ that make sense, but how, I don’t know.

I ask this question to understand the following equalities

\begin{aligned} 
( f | f ) _ { H ^ { k } \left( \mathbf { R } ^ { N } \right) } & = \frac { 1 } { ( 2 \pi ) ^ { N } } \int _ { \mathbf { R } ^ { N } } \Big( \sum _ { | \alpha | \leq k } \xi ^ { 2 \alpha } \Big) | \mathcal { F } f ( \xi ) | ^ { 2 } d \xi \\ 
& = \frac { 1 } { ( 2 \pi ) ^ { N } } \int _ { \mathbf { R } ^ { N } } \left( 1 + | \xi | ^ { 2 } \right) ^ { k } | \mathcal { F } f ( \xi ) | ^ { 2 } d \xi 
\end{aligned}

Thank you

Comment: we just sum it as a geometric series

Comment: Yes, I tried that but I didn't find the result, I'll try again

Comment: find out if $\alpha$ is a multi-index in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or just $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: $\alpha \in \mathbf { N } ^ { N }$

Comment: $k \in \mathbf { N } ^ { * }$, $f \in \mathcal { S } ^ { \prime } \left( \mathbf { R } ^ { N } \right)$, $\alpha \in \mathbf { N } ^ { N }$

 $\Omega$ open set of  $\mathbf { R } ^ { N } $, $k \in \mathbf { N }$ and $H ^ { k } ( \Omega )$ is defined by
$$
H ^ { k } ( \Omega ) = \left\{ f \in L ^ { 2 } ( \Omega ) | \partial ^ { \alpha } f \in L ^ { 2 } ( \Omega ) \text { pour } | \alpha | \leq k \right\}
$$